# Является ли строка палиндромом(пишется одинаково в обе стороны)

Tags: java, строки

Нужно определить является ли строка палиндромом. *Палиндромом* называется строка, которая пишется одинаково слева направо и справа налево (в том числе пустая). При определении "*палиндромности*" строки должны учитываться только буквы и цифры. **А пробелы, знаки препинания, а также регистр символов должны игнорироваться.**

*Sample Input:*
**Madam, I'm Adam!**

*Sample Output:*
**true**

убрать пробелы можно с помощью `.replace(" ","");`
а как  отфильтровать строку от знаков препинания?
общий код который работает на строки без знаков препинания:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arr {

public Boolean vozvrat(String A){

    String B="";
    String C=A.replace(" ","");
    char[] mass =C.toCharArray();
    char[] mass2=new char[mass.length];
    for ( int i =mass.length-1; i>= 0;){
        for(int j=0;j<mass2.length; j++){

        mass2[j]=mass[i]; i--;

B+=mass2[j];

        }

    }
    System.out.println(B);
    System.out.println(C);
    return B.equalsIgnoreCase(C);

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Arr C=new Arr();
    System.out.println(C.vozvrat("Madam'      I'm Adam"));
}

}
```

Comment: мне одному кажется, что эта задача без циклов прекрасно решается?

Answer (score 11):

Метод определяет является ли строка палиндромом. Решение в одну строчку.

- `replaceAll("\\W","")`: убираем из строки все не нужные символы (знаки             препинания, пробелы и т.д.);
- `new StringBuilder`: создаем вторую строку, но пересортированную в обратном порядке с помощью метода `reverse()`;
- `equalsIgnoreCase`: сравниваем их между собой, игнорируя регистр.

Код:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("\\W","")
               .equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(text.replaceAll("\\W",""))
               .reverse().toString());
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 5):

Вот решение Вашей проблемы:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {

            System.out.print("Sample input: ");
            String input = inputStream.readLine();
            System.out.print("Sample output: ");
            System.out.print(isPalindrome(input));

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.err.println("Input error");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while (matcher.find())
            builder.append(matcher.group());

        String result = builder.toString();
        String reverseResult = builder.reverse().toString();

        if(result.compareToIgnoreCase(reverseResult) == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPD**: немного не учёл Ваш код, можете в `vozvrat` скопировать мой метод `isPalindrome`.

Comment: @typemoon вообще то я использовал регулярное выражение. Я выбрал все буквы из строки и слепил их воедино с помощью `StringBuilder`, а затем сравнил полученную строку (`builder.toString()`), с перевёрнутой строкой (`builder.reverse().toString()`). Плохой из Вас троль, здесь нет прохода в цикле с начала и с конца.

Answer (score 3):

спасибо Alexander Smirnov но так более понятней будет

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String text) {
    text = text.replaceAll("\\W","");//удаляем все ненужное
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(text);
    strBuilder.reverse(); //переворачиваем строку
    String invertedText = strBuilder.toString();//присваиваем перевернутую строку

    return text.equalsIgnoreCase(invertedText) ;//возвращаем сравнение двух строк вне зависимости от регистра

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Составьте регулярку, включающую только буквы и цифры.
2. Разбейте строку на массив.
3. В цикле пробегитесь по массиву, проверяя на условие вхождения в регулярку. Если не входит, заменяйте на `""`.
4. В итоге у вас на выходе строка без пробелов и знаков препинания.

Comment: Мне представляется более правильным посимвольно сравнивать строку двигаясь от ее начала и конца к середине и использовать метод `Character.isLetterOrDigit` для отбрасывания ненужных символов.

Comment: почему нельзя полностью пробежаться от начала до конца?

Comment: Пожалуй вы правы) Только сначала надо лишнее выбросить, а потом уж к середине двигаться)

Comment: "Составьте регулярку," Нельзя плз поподробнее( недавно только начал изучать java)

Comment: Не нужны никакие регулярки. Вообще не нужны. Лучше выбрасывать "по ходу". Т.е. `for(i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) { while (i < j && badchar(str.charAt(i)) i++; while(...) j--; ...` / Думаю, идея ясна, как сравнивать в lowcase найдете

Answer (score 1):

спасибо, вот еще сделал, немного калично но тоже работает

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arr {

    public Boolean vozvrat(String A) {
        String K = "";
        String B = "";
        char[] mass0 = A.toCharArray();
        for (int l = 0; l < mass0.length - 1; l++) {
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(mass0[l]) == false) {
                l++;
            }
            K += mass0[l];
        }
        K = K.replace(" ", "");
        char[] mass = K.toCharArray();
        char[] mass2 = new char[mass.length];
        for (int i = mass.length - 1; i >= 0;) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++) {
                mass2[j] = mass[i];
                i--;
                B += mass2[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(A);
        System.out.println(K);
        System.out.println(B);
        return B.equalsIgnoreCase(K);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Arr C = new Arr();
        System.out.println(C.vozvrat("Madam, I'm Adam!"));
    }
}
```